# Need to supress sops for second duplicate String onwards.

Tags: java, selenium, duplicates

```
import java.util.HashSet;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;


public class Demo27 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
     {

        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                driver.get("file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/listDropdown.html");

                WebElement listElement=driver.findElement(By.id("countrySelect"));

                Select select=new Select(listElement);

                List<WebElement> elements=select.getOptions();

                int count=elements.size();

                HashSet<String> set=new HashSet<String>();

                for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {

                        WebElement singleElement=elements.get(i);

                        String text=singleElement.getText();

                        if(!set.add(text))
            {
                System.out.println(text+"is duplicated");
            }

        }

        driver.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does my answer help? What do you mean by second duplicate String?

Comment: United Statesis duplicated
Europe is duplicated
Europe is duplicated- i dont want this coming(2nd duplicated element)

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check it out!

Comment: Thank You...It works!!!!....Am new to java, can you suggest how to improve my coding logic?

Comment: Hmm, You have to better write the logic in paper and get into coding. that's how i started.. Please accept the answer to close the question. Choose the right tick on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a logic this way. I have created an `ArrayList` to capture the duplicate values. I will have it for reference if the incoming text is found in the duplicate list. If it is not present, then i will print it. Otherwise, i will just ignore. This way you can suppress the second duplicate text to be printed

```
     boolean isSet = false;
     List<String> duplicates = new ArrayList<String>();
     if((isSet = set.add(text))){
      //this will get printed for only unique values added
         System.out.println(text+"is unique");
       }
      else{
        if(!duplicates.contains(text)){
        duplicates.add(text);
        System.out.println(text+"is first duplicate");
        }
      }
```